# Call javascript function with value in code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How to call JavaScript function with value from ASP.NET code behind?
I have JavaScript function and I am using it in a div tag

but when i call my function nothing happen !
why ?

( my parameter is path of picture and i want set this path in my div tag to view picture. )

my html code :

```
<div id="myPano" class="pano">

    </div>
```

my javascript

```
 <script>
    function myFunction(imgz) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myPano").pano({
                img: imgz

            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

and code behind ( button click )

```
 Dim imgz As String
    imgz = "img/sphere.jpg"
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "myFunction(" & imgz & ")", True)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to add a string to the value:

```
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "myFunction('" & imgz & "')", True)
```

and you don't have to put your `.pano` code inside dom ready:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(imgz) {
        $("#myPano").pano({
            img: imgz
        });
    }
</script>
```